# How to get the result of a WWWPost in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I'm trying to learn how to make a POST using unity's WWWForms in C#. However after trying a few examples in the docs I still can't figure out how to get the result or even know if it's posting successfully. Here is the page where the code I got is from https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html

I've tried making an infinite loop in main and assigning a static variable when the post is done but it is never assigned. At first I thought it was because the console was closing too quickly but it wasn't that.

```
class Program : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string url = "http://images.earthcam.com/ec_metros/ourcams/fridays.jpg";
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
        {
            yield return www;
            Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

I expected it to print success after response was sent back but instead it closes.

Comment: WWW is now obsolete. Based on your code it seems you want to download and show an image as a texture right? You don't want to use WWW (neither post) for that, you can use UnityWebRequest. Check the documentation here : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual//UnityWebRequest-RetrievingTexture.html

Comment: I understand that but I'm looking at some legacy code that uses WWW so I want to understand how it works and how to use it.

Comment: By the way, `static void Main(string[] args)` is not needed. Unity will call all the magic methods for you and had its own entry point. Yours will go unused.

Comment: If you want to know how it works, the implementation of your code is wrong. (Unity docs have half code sometimes).IEnumerator cannot be treated as a method. Also IEnumerators pause and wait for a ```yield``` return. You have to start a ```coroutine``` passing your IEnumerator to work. Change your Start IEnumerator to something else (eg : ImageDown) and start a coroutine from your Start method. ```StartCoroutine(ImageDown());```

Answer (score 0):

## Two things

1. `IEnumerator Start()` is a coroutine. This means that it will pause and resume execution as needed, specified by the `yield` return value. If you want to think of coroutines like threads, you can, but just understand that (a) they aren't and (b) they're managed for you.
2. Your code won't run unless it is attached to a game object in a scene.

You appear to new coming from non-Unity development, evidenced by the `static void Main` and referencing the console Window closing too quickly. Unity is **not** a console application and is magic methods are only invoked when appropriate, in this case, when each GameObject with this component attached to it is first initialized. You can't just `import Unity` and expect it to work like any other library (Unity is not a library).

Comment: Thanks very much, this answers my question.